# Permissions for seeing translated custom menu link items

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a problem with custom menu link translations.

Only users with permissions to 'Translate custom menu link' (translate menu_link_content) are able to see the translated strings.

For example if I log in as admin, I can see the link texts changing when switching languages. 
But when I switch languages as an anonymous user the link texts fall back to the default language. Translated routes are working correctly.

As a workaround I could just give all users the 'translate menu_link_content' -permission but that seems like a possible security flaw.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your menu link translations are actually published, there's a checkbox in the edit form. I think there are some bugs there that this isn't set properly when doing it from a node edit form.

Comment: That indeed was the case. The checkbox wasn't displaying at all in node-edit-form. We ended up installing [hook_post_action - module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_post_action) and manipulating the link in HOOK_node_postsave(). After having little success with editing the menu link entity, we ended up doing it directly to database. [Here's the gist.](https://gist.github.com/hannupaasonen/38d2fda147d62dfdededa3d8f734abd3) Thanks for help!

Comment: You don't need that module, a hook_node_update() should work fine for that as well for your case. But fine as long as it works. You could also check the issue queue and report this as a bug, because I think it is one.